# Kotlin Android Recycler view inside Fragment with Bottom Navigation not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, kotlin

I am trying to develop  social networking app which uses Android Jetpack Libraries but while using Navigation Component to use bottom navigation to navigate through fragments inside an activity , This Adapter throws an error at **LayoutInflator()** which causes app to crash

Can anyone help me through this:

[image]

My Adapter Class:

```
class FeedAdapter : PagedListAdapter<feed,FeedAdapter.ViewHolder>(FeedDiffCallBack()){
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val userPost = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.feedrow,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(userPost)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val feedItem = getItem(position)
    if(feedItem != null){
        holder.bind(feedItem)
    }
}

class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    //Retrieve data
    private val username:TextView = itemView.post_name

    private val userPic:ImageView = itemView.feedImage1
    private val location:TextView = itemView.postLocation
    private val time:TextView = itemView.postTime
    private val post:ImageView = itemView.postImage

    fun bind(feed: feed) = with(itemView){
        //TODO:Bind Data with View
            showFeedData(feed)

    }

    private fun showFeedData(feed: feed) {
        username.text = feed.username
        userPic.setImageURI(null)
        userPic.visibility = View.GONE
        location.text = feed.location
        time.text = feed.timeStamp.toString()
        post.setImageURI(Uri.parse(feed.mUrl))

    }

}

 }

class FeedDiffCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<feed>() {
override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem:feed, newItem: feed): Boolean {
    return oldItem?.id == newItem?.id
}

override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: feed, newItem: feed): Boolean {
    return oldItem == newItem
}

}
```

Fragment Class:

```
class FeedFragment : Fragment() {

companion object {
    fun newInstance() = FeedFragment()
}

private lateinit var viewModel: FeedViewModel
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_fragment, container, false)
    val context = getContext() ?: return view

    val factory = InjectorUtils.provideViewModelFactory(context)
    viewModel = 
 ViewModelProviders.of(this,factory).get(FeedViewModel::class.java)
    val adapter = FeedAdapter()
    view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.feedView).adapter = adapter
    view.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.feedView).layoutManager = 
LinearLayoutManager(MyApplication.getContext())
    subscribeUI(adapter)
    return view
}

private fun subscribeUI(adapter: FeedAdapter) {
    viewModel.showFeed().observe(this, object:Observer<PagedList<feed>>{
        override fun onChanged(t: PagedList<feed>?) {
            adapter.submitList(t)
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

    })
}


override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
}
```

}

feed_row.xml
Individual item for recycler view -->

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/postContainer"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_parent_rounded_corner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--TODO:Change to Circle Image View-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/postDetail_1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/post_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/LabelStyle"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/sf_pro_display_semibold" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/postDetail_2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postTime"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/postImage"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postDetail_1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
       />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How are you binding the view objects to the XML file? It looks like you're maybe using kotlin android extensions. If that is the case, I see that some of the fields like `feedImage1` don't exist in your XML file

Comment: I cleared out that!!! But still the same error is raising ,When I try to debug Adapter using breakpoints ,LayoutInflator.from(),inflate() function causes this thing!!! @NicolásCarrasco

Answer (score 0):

> Your issue might be in this method,
>
> ```
> override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
>    val feedItem = getItem(position)
>    if(feedItem != null){
>       holder.bind(feedItem)
>    }
> }
> ```

Your **`ViewHolder`** is using **`poisition`** from method parameter which might be inconsistent

[See from here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)),

So, you should change line to this:

```
val feedItem = getItem(holder.adapterPosition)
```

instead of

```
val feedItem = getItem(position)
```

I hope it resolves the issue.

Comment: No!!! That doesn't solve the issue!!!! It says the same, Binary XML file line:#3 Error inflating class layout and shows error occured at LayoutInflator method inside onCreateView() in Adapter @Jeel Vankhede

Comment: can you show your `imports` for `kotlin extensions` ? @Dilip

Comment: It's working now,I don't know how but i just added **xmlns:app** and **xmlns:tools** lines in layout file and it started working

Answer (score 0):

This might help some one looking for the same Exception to be cleared :
What I did is that my **feed_row.xml** above is included inside **< layout >** tags and I changed it in this way , So the exception got cleared:

*Before Exception:*

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

*After changing to this Exception cleared:*

```
 <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
```

I don't know how it works but it did work!!! So Anyone who knows what happens there can explain please!